# How to make an input a file name?

Tags: matlab, input

I would like to take an input from the user and make this input a file name which I will be writing on my code after taking the input.

I would be appreciated if you could help me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should add a tag for the programming language you are writing your code in, please.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to ask for code without giving what you have so far.

Answer (score 3):

**MATLAB**

```
filename = input('File name: ','s');
fileID = fopen(filename)
fprintf(fileID, 'That wasn''t so hard')
fclose(fileID)
```

- [`input`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) - Request user input
- [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html) - Open file, or obtain information about open files
- [`fprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html) - Write data to text file

---

**Python**

```py
filename = raw_input('File name: ')
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write('That wasn\'t so hard')
```

---

**C**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char filename[81];
    FILE* f;

    while (1) {
        printf("File name: ");
        if (scanf("%80s") == 1) break;
    }

    f = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (!f) {
        perror("opening file");
        return 1;
    }

    fprintf(f, "That wasn't so hard\n");
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

---

**sh script**

```sh
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "File name: "
read filename

echo "That wasn't so hard" > $filename
```

Comment: how do you know he is using Python?

Comment: @Ol'Reliable I don't. I'll just keep trying languages until I find one he likes, I suppose...

Comment: @user3162870 Ah... might have taken me a while to get to that one. *Don't you think it would have been nice to mention that?!*

Comment: Where'd be the fun in that? ;)